# Error en código de calculo de producto entre dos Matrices

Tags: c

estoy tratando de multiplicar dos matrices pero tengo un problema en una variable y no se cual es, les adjunto el codigo de la funcion y el error que me tira

```
int multiplicarMatriz (int filas, int columnas, int a[FILAS_MATRIZ_A][COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_A], int b[FILAS_MATRIZ_B][COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_B])
{
    int producto [FILAS_MATRIZ_B][COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_B];
    for (int a = 0; a <COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_B; a++) {

        for (int i=0; i< FILAS_MATRIZ_A; i++) {
            int suma = 0;

            for (int j=0; j<COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_A; j++) {

                suma = suma + (a[i][j] * b[j][a]);
            }

            producto[i][a] = suma;
        }
    }


    return producto;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error se debe por la forma como retornas el valor. La función retorna un valor de tipo `int` y vos estás devolviendo un *array*. Ahí está el problema, no puedes hacer eso. Ahí te toca usar memoria dinámica para hacer que la matriz sea **dinámica** (con la función `malloc`). Sin embargo, deberás liberar la memoria manualmente con la función `free`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema, la variable `producto` que retornas a la aplicación es una variable local a la función, y por tanto deja de existir cuando la función termina.

Por otro lado, como te indican en otra respuesta, para multiplicar dos matrices, el producto debe tener las mismas filas que la matriz A y las mismas columnas que la matriz B, y la iteración del bucle mas interno debe ser sobre el valor común que deben tener las columnas de la matriz A y las filas de la matriz B.  Es dedir `COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_A == FILAS_MATRIZ_B`.

Otra tercera cosa que puede ser muy interesante, de cara a multiplicar matrices rectangulares, es en lugar de manejar arrays bidimensionales, hacerlo con arrays de punteros a arrays.  De ese modo, puedes pasar las dimensiones como parámetros y no tienes que fijar los tamaños de los arrays en tiempo de compilación.

Para solucionar tu problema del retorno, lo mejor es que hagas una de estas dos cosas:

- Pasas una referencia a tu matriz resultado, que puedes asegurar su tamaño si le pones como dimensiones las filas de A y las columnas de B.  Las dimensiones son fijadas en tiempo de compilación, para poder manejar arrays bidimensionales.

```
#define FILAS_A        4
#define COLUMNAS_A     3
#define FILAS_B        3 /* TIENE QUE SER IGUAL QUE COLUMNAS_A */
#define COLUMNAS_B     8

#if COLUMNAS_A != FILAS_B
#error FILAS_B tiene que ser igual a COLUMNAS_A
#endif

void producto(
         double A[FILAS_A][COLUMNAS_A], 
         double B[FILAS_B][COLUMNAS_B], 
         double P[FILAS_A][COLUMNAS_B])
{
    int fila;
    for (fila = 0; fila < FILAS_A; ++fila) {
        int columna;

        for (columna = 0; columna < COLUMNAS_B; ++columna) {
            double acumulado = 0.0;
            int i;

            for (i = 0; i < COLUMNAS_A /* o FILAS_B, da igual */; ++i) {
                acumulado += A[fila][i] * B[i][columna];
            }

            P[fila][columna] = acumulado;
        }
    }
} /* producto */
```

- Retornas una matriz al efecto que has construido llamando a `malloc()` y usando memoria dinámica.

```
typedef double **matriz;

static matriz crea_matriz(int filas, int columnas)
{
    matriz result = calloc(filas, sizeof *result);
    if (!result) {
        perror("calloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    int f;
    for (f = 0; f < filas; ++f) {
        result[f] = calloc(columnas, sizeof **result);
        if (!result[f]) {
            perror("calloc"); 
            /* retornamos la memoria */
            libera_matriz(result, filas, columnas);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

void libera_matriz(matriz A, filas, columnas)
{
    if (!A) return; /* por si falla crea_matriz */
    int f;

    for (f = 0; f < filas; ++f) { 
        /* si no obtuvimos la memoria, al crear fila f */
        if (!A[f]) break;

        free(A[f]); /* liberamos la fila */
    }
    free(A); /* liberamos los punteros de las filas. */
} /* libera_matriz */

matriz producto_matrices(
        int      filas_a, 
        matriz   A,
        int cols_a_filas_b, /* columnas de a debe ser igual que filas de B, 
                             * asi que solo lo pasamos una vez. */ 
        matriz   B,
        int cols_b)
{
    matriz producto = crea_matriz(filas_a, cols_b);

    int f;
    for (f = 0; f < filas_a; ++f) {
        int c;
        for (c = 0; c < cols_b; ++c) {
            double acum = 0.0;

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < cols_a_filas_b; ++i) {
                acum += A[f][i] * B[i][c];
            }
            producto[f][c] = acum;
        }
    }

    return producto; /* ahora sí */
} /* producto */
```

De esta manera puedes crear matrices de cualquier tamaño y multiplicarlas con:

```
    /* crea las matrices */
    matriz A = crea_matriz(filas_a,        cols_a_filas_b),
           B = crea_matriz(cols_a_filas_b, columnas_b);

    /* inicializa las matrices (el codigo las inicializa con ceros)
     * ... */

    matriz C = producto(filas_a, A, cols_a_filas_b, B, columnas_b);
    /* imprime C */
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la solucion, intente hacer la primera pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo primero que debes considerar es la regla de multiplicación de matrices, siempre hay que verificar que las columnas de la primera matriz, sean iguales que las filas de la segunda matriz, es decir, estás asumiendo que:

`int producto [FILAS_MATRIZ_B][COLUMNAS_MATRIZ_B];`ya son las dimensiones de esta nueva matriz.

Me parece que en algún punto apuntas a memoria que no es válida.